# How to get users from a group, with a union between two relationships in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, union

I want to recieve all users from a group.
The problem is in this group their are student users (with a pivot table) and normal users.
So i have to merge them together, but i still want to maintain all possibilities from eloquent.
I came to this:

```
dd($this->belongsToMany(User::class)->union($this->hasManyThrough(User::class,Student::class,'class_id','id','id','user_id'))->get());
```

But as result i get:
[image]

My database relationships

```
Users
- id
Group
- id
Students
- id
- user_id (fk to users)
- class_id (fk to groups)
User_Group
- user_id (fk to users)
- group_id (fk to groups)
```

User-model:

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
}

public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
}
```

Student-model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function class()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class, 'class_id');
}
```

Group-model

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Student::class, 'class_id');
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function members()
{
    //this causes the problem!!
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->union($this->hasManyThrough(User::class,Student::class,'class_id','id','id','user_id'));

}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but the issue here is that the two sides of the union do not have the same number/type of columns.  Fix that, and the error should go away.

Comment: I know but i can't fix it with a select from only the table users.*, i tried it with add on both sides from the union a select('users.*'), but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I noticed you can make use of
`        DB::table('users')
        ->join('groups', function ($join) {
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'group_user.user_id')->orOn('students.class_id', '=', 'groups.id');
        })`
But this doesn't solve the pivot tables group_users and students

Answer (score 1):

in User model relationship

```
public function group(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);

}
```

in Group model relationship

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_group');

}
```

in Students model relationship

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');

}

public function group(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'class_id', 'id');

}
```

you can call now

```
$users = User::whereHas('groups',function ($query){
                  $query->where('group_id',1);
               })->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, because i already can get my users from a certain class, i only can't merge them with a user that is directly linked with the group. So a class is a group, and users can be linked  directly to a group, but also with the students class to a group: so user -> group and user -> student (user_id, class_id) -> group, and from a group i need the users as well as the students, in eloquent model. i edit my question with all the things i already have in my models

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have two relations from one model to another, due pivot tables. In my example you could go from users to groups with the relation user_groups and the relation students. To get all users that belong to a certain group i need to call both relations. To solve this issue, i made use of Abdulmajeed's example to solve it. You can see the code below. Thanks for helping me out.

```
public function members()
{
    return User::whereHas('groups', function($q)
    {
        $q->where('id',$this->id);
    })->orWhereHas('students', function($q)
    {
        $q->where('class_id',$this->id);
    });
}
```